# value of locals in GDB "bt full" output

Tags: gdb

"bt full" stack trace in GDB shows the locals in each of the frame. Does it always show values of the locals at the entry of the function or the updated value of the locals when "bt full" is executed?

Answer (score 1):

It shows the values of variables at the current point in each frame.

The way this works is that a variable's debugging information carries a description of the variable's location.  gdb evaluates this description, then fetches the value from the location.  Now, this can be complicated (variables can be in registers at one spot and in memory at another; or structures on the stack can be broken into their constituent parts; etc) -- but in the simple case this is just some location on the stack.  So, if the variable is assigned to, the old value is overwritten.

However, if you are using a new-enough gcc and a new-enough gdb, you can in some cases see entry values for function arguments.  An entry value might look like `var@entry = 72`.  This means that the compiler was able to tell the debugger how to compute the value-at-entry.  This is normally done by unwinding one frame and evaluating a DWARF expression that says how to compute the value given the state in the calling frame.